# Check if a set of lines exist in a file and then print " found" else not "found"

Tags: python

how can i find if a set of lines are present in a file and if present print "found" else "not found" using python.

Also if the line is not found i need the process to terminate and should not search for next line.
suppose the file contain data:

hi welcome to python

this is nice

this is bad

this is good

this is not correct

this is bad

this is bad for health

this is good for health

Here if this is good not present then i need the process to stop there and should not go to search for this is bad.

This is my current attempt

```
with open("model.log" , "r") as f:
      lines = f.read().split('\n')
      for line in lines:
          if "this is good" in line:
              print('Found the line and going to next level')
          else:
              print('not found')
              
          if "this is bad" in line:
             print('Found this line')
          else:
              print('stuck at the previous line')
             
          if "good for health" in line:
              print('Found it is there')
          else:
              print('error')
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: i want to print the if condition when line is present in file and else condition if line is not present.  eg  Found the line and going to next level , stuck at the previous line ( when line "this is bad" is not present) and terminate after that. if else condition is printed then there is no need of reading further lines.

Comment: Does your code already did that?

Comment: my code is printing the else condition if line is not present but instead of terminating it is reading next line and checking whether line is present or not.( i have already tried giving `break`) but its not working.

Comment: Have you tried using `elif`?

Comment: yes, still it is not working.

Comment: have you tried using `exit(0)` to terminate the loop instead of `break`?

Answer (score 1):

The `break` statement can be used to terminate a loop prematurely.
[This](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=break#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) might help.

E.g.:

```
 for line in lines:
          if "this is good" in line:
              print('Found the line and going to next level')
          else:
              print('not found')
              break #This will break the loop & execution will jumpt next line after loop
```

Comment: then is there any method by which i can terminate the process if line is not found?

Comment: also when i give break after else it is showing invalid.

Comment: @arathivsuresh you need to first learn basics of python

Comment: i have done this already and when i run this only else condition is getting printed even if  if condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("model.log" , "r") as f:
  lines = f.read().split('\n')
  for line in list(enumerate(lines, start=1)):
        if "this is good" == line[1]:
              print(f'Found in line {line[0]}')
```

Comment: thanks i'll try this method but what about else condition? and one more problem is that how to terminate the process if else condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

```
lines_to_search = ["this is good","this is bad","good for health"]

with open("model.log" , "r") as f:
      file_lines = f.readlines()

      for line in lines_to_serch:
          if line in file_lines:
              print(f"Found \"{line}\"")
          else:
              print(f"Not Found \"{line}\"")
              break
```

Comment: the problem is i need to print different comments for different lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can try without `for` loop:

```
with open("model.log") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    if "this is good" in lines:
        print('Found the line and going to next level')
    else:
        print('not found')

    if "this is bad" in lines:
        print('Found this line')
    else:
        print('stuck at the previous line')

    if "good for health" in lines:
        print('Found it is there')
    else:
        print('error')
```